# Проблема с выводом списка

Tags: erlang

Стоит задача: преобразовать список, к примеру,

```
[{a,3}, b, {c,2}, {a,2}] в [a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a].
```

То есть в каждом кортеже указан атом и количество его повторений.

```
decode([]) -> [];
decode([H | T]) -> [decode(H) | decode(T)] ;
decode({X, 1}) -> [X];
decode({X, Y}) -> [X | decode({X, Y - 1})];
decode(X) -> X.
```

Но это решение возвращает `[[a,a,a],b,[c,c],[a,a]]`. Как изменить код, чтобы получить необходимый результат?

Дополнительное условие: не использовать никаких библиотечных функций.

Comment: Ну можете применить к результату lists:flatten. Т.е. ввести вспомогательную функцию (приведённую Вами выше), а decode описать как применение lists:flatten к результату этой функции.

Comment: Увы, так поступить нельзя - условие - без использования библиотечных функций.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну можно flatten реализовать, это несложно (1). А можно заменить `[decode(H) | decode(T)]` на `decode(H) ++ decode(T)` (заодно и заменив `decode(X)`, чтобы давал в результате список из одного элемента):

```
 decode([]) -> [];
 decode([H | T]) -> decode(H) ++ decode(T) ;
 decode({X, 1}) -> [X];
 decode({X, Y}) -> [X | decode({X, Y - 1})];
 decode(X) -> [X].
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле в большинстве случаев не стоит использовать рекурсию в явном виде, потому что читаемость кода от нее очень страдает. К тому же, в большинстве случаев она нарушает принцип Single responsibily, когда вы в одном месте смешиваете и логику задачи, и обход по списку.

Почти для всего уже есть готовые функции, например, проще всего, хотя, конечно, и не так оптимально по алгоритмической сложности, будет написать так:

```
decode(L) ->
    lists:flatmap(
        fun
            ({E, Cnt}) -> lists:duplicate(Cnt, E);
            (E) -> [E]
        end, L).
```